# Seaborn: stripplot x-log scale collapses values

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Hi I am trying to use stripplot in seaborn with log scale for the x-axis. It seems that the path I have taken does not work as intended. I would appreciate if someone could help me with that.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(-8, -2, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)

sns.stripplot(x,y)
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
```

all the xvalues are collapsed on the right edge of the plot (see plot). I works fine if I set the y-axis to be log.

[image]

PS: I would also need to restrict the number of x tick labels.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you aiming to do here? The x variable in a stripplot is treated as categorical — it doesn't make sense to take a log of a categorical variable. This function is not meant to be used to make a standard scatterplot.

Comment: Exactly what you said to get a scatter plot. I did not realize x needed to be categorical, now I get it.  How would you do scatter plot with coloring according to a third column then ? PS: different markdown according to a fourth column would also be great.

Answer (score 1):

A scatter plot on a log scale using [`pyplot.scatter`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.scatter):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(-8, -2, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)
c = np.random.rand(10)
s = 20+np.random.rand(10)*40

plt.scatter(x,y, c=c, s=s, cmap="jet")
plt.gca().set_xscale('log')
plt.xlim(5e-9, 5e-2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

The same scatter plot on a linear scale:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.logspace(-8, -2, 10)
y = np.linspace(0, 100, 10)
c = np.random.rand(10)
s = 20+np.random.rand(10)*40

plt.scatter(x,y, c=c, s=s, cmap="jet")
plt.xlim(-0.003, 0.012)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The issue here is to generate the legend automatically for each color ?

Comment: You did not mention a legend in the question. How should the legend look like? Here we have 10 different colors, so you want 10 differen legend entries? Or a colorbar?